# Copying a file from github

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted a folder from a project. However, I pushed this folder on github and have it there. How can I retrieve this folder? (copy it from github to my local files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and restore the [folder from your local history](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/18/restoring-a-directory-from-history.html) (which include the history that you have pushed to GitHub)

```
git checkout <treeish> -- /path/to/dir
```

Replace  with the SHA1 of the most recent commit where you can still see that folder.